# Why does end-of-line behave differently in --batch?

Tags: let-binding, batch-mode

I have an elisp script that behaves differently between an interactive Emacs session and running Emacs with `--batch`.

```
(defun call-fn-in-let (unused)
  (let (xx)
    (let (yy)
      (split-string "foo" "bar" nil))))

(with-temp-buffer
  (insert "foofoofoo\nbarbarbar")
  (let ((dd (let (aa)
              (let (bb)
                (let (cc)
                  (progn (call-fn-in-let nil)))))))
    (let (ee)
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (if t
            (progn
              (move-end-of-line nil)
              (message "point is: %s" (point))))))))
```

If I run `M-x eval-buffer`, then `*Messages*` shows:

```
point is: 10
```

However, if I run Emacs from the CLI, `end-of-line` behaves differently, jumping straight to end the of the file.

```
$ emacs -batch -l test/pyimport-test.el
point is: 20
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.5.1
```

I'm mystified why this is the case.

This is the most minimal example I can find. Even removing things like `if t` or an unused let binding, changes the `-batch` behaviour!

Comment: I've received a helpful bit of advice that `(goto-char (point-at-eol))` works around the problem. However, I can't see why end-of-line changes.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug? I see it with 24.5.1, but not with Emacs 25 pretest (25.0.95) (i.e. Emacs 25 prints 17 and 23 in batch mode too)

Comment: @npostavs I'm coming to the same conclusion. I've just compiled HEAD (commit 8419f0d166cf5107) and I can't replicate there.